# Run asp.net core app in production with path prefix

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-linux

I have an *asp.net core* web api, which I can start from the command line (on linux hosts)

```
dotnet MyWebApi.dll
```

This will start *some webserver* that listens on `localhost:5000` (per default).
Let's assume I have a `ValuesController` that listens to path `/values/`. Thus I can get my values from `http://localhost:5000/values/`, all good.

What I need now is to add a prefix `api` for all the local paths in the api, so the values controller would respond on: `localhost:5000/api/values`.

I can't find an elegant way to do this. 
Obviously I could change it in the controller's route configuration - but that's very redundant and requires a lot of changes, as we have many controllers, and we use `[Route(..)]` attributes on the controllers themselves.

I've seen the `applicationUrl` property in the `launchsettings.json` file in my webapi project. Apparently it contains the configuration used for the Visual Studio debugging/launching. Adding a prefix there (through project properties > debug) works fine and does exactly what I need, but that only works for starting it from VisualStudio (i.e. `dotnet run`). In the production environment I only have the `dotnet publish` artifacts available - the  `launchsettings.json` file is not copied over there and there seems no way to provide such a file to the `dotnet [assembly]` launch command (like with dotnet run).

---

A bit of background for why I need this: 
The pattern of having the api controllers listen at `/` comes from IIS, because there it's common to add apps in subfolders of sites, which handles the path prefixing part. I now deploy my app with docker and the api has its own container, where it's started with the above command - thus the prefix is missing and I need to add it back somehow.

Comment: Isn't `/api/` the *default* route prefix for Web API? What does your routing code look like?

Comment: The attributes are on the class `[Route("values")] public class ValuesController { ... }` and on the method `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]` etc.

Comment: Which someone had to modify and *remove* the `api` prefix that is added by default. By default it's there, in fact the text should be `[Route("api/[controller]")]`. In any case, this is 100% about routing. You can specify routes with attributes, during configuration or a mix. Using attributes is the easiest way unless you decide to *change* all routes after creating a lot of controllers.

Comment: Routing is described in [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1). If you're just starting a new project though, why not simply create a *new* one with `dotnet new webapi` that will have the default routes?

Comment: You should probably check [Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.1) as well. It's a way to define route "namespaces" that will map only to controllers of a specific area. For example the routes for the `Blog` area would only look for controllers that have the `[Area("Blog")]` attribute. You may be able to just add the `{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"` route and add the `Area` attribute to any controller you want without explicitly specifying all route areas

Comment: I don't fully understand the interplay between the .MapRoute(...) method and using attributes. The attributes seem to overrule the MapRoute setup. In any case, I think I have a solution (which I will test and post as answer if successful). Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution that does the trick, in `Startup.cs` I added `UseBasePath`:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // .. 

        app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api"));
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

This allows getting the values from `localhost:5000/api/values` ***and*** `localhost:5000/values`. I don't really need or like this ambiguity, but it solves my problem for now.

Comment: Instead of covering things app why not *fix* them? Why was `api/` removed from the code in the first place? Why not put it back? After all, it's just a File Replace for `[Route("` with `[Route("api/`. Or better yet, a regex replace that would remove *all* hard-coded `Route` attributes and replace them with `"api/[controller]"`

Comment: Because our API was previously running on IIS, as part of a site consisting of a SinglePageApp + API. The SPA was in main site and the API was added underneath as an "Application" with alias `/api`. So with the original (default template) prefix, the api calls had to be `xyz.com/api/api/values` ... but now we switched to docker, where the api is really standalone, but routing-wise it makes sense to expose it to the outside world in the same, classic 'IIS' way.

Comment: These aren't different ways. It's the exact same routing. It shouldn't have been hard-coded in the first place, otherwise a simple change to `MapRoute` or `MapAreaRoute` would be enough. Right now there are many issues - what happens if you want to change a name? You'll have to change both the controller's name *and* the `Route` attribute, or juggle different names

Comment: Instead of `UsePathBase` I'd try using `MapRoute` first. Worst case, both routes would apply - both `api/Values` and `Values`, which is what `UsePathBase` does now. The advantage is that now you can start fixing individual controllers

Comment: Not that `UsePathBase` is wrong - [this Github issue discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/893) explains the motivation behind it and why it doesn't disable the root - it would play havoc with middleware classes. It's meant to handle deployment issues, just like the one you have.

Comment: Ah.. I see, your main issue is that we're not using the default `{controller}/{action}/{id?}` routing, right? - Well... I respect that opinion, but that's just a different topic and I think we have commented off-topic enough already. ;-) Thanks in for your input in any case, I will consider reworking the routing.

Comment: You rarely need to do so. Ideally, the Kestrel server runs behind a reverse proxy server, where you can easily modify the URL. Messing up your code is pointless, unless you really want to deploy the Kestrel server alone.

Comment: @Lex Li: Yes, that's exactly the setup we have, and for most parts that works perfectly fine. The only problem I had was that _swagger_ didn't work right anymore - as it was not aware of the upstream request-rewriting done by nginx, it declared the endpoints without the path prefix.

Comment: Thanks, I have the same problem with our API, they put the api server behind a proxy with a prefix, and now the swagger generated curl requests via the UI no longer work because they do not add the prefix.